# Swig java c ++ passing a vector of vectors containing a c++ structure

Tags: java, c++, stl, vector, swig

I have been looking around at the relevant questions and i cannot get rid of the swig pointer.

Basically i have a simple structure

```
typedef struct mbuf{
 int date
 int time
}
```

and within my class i define a vector of vectors

```
class Profile {

private:

    std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> > mbufArray;

    std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> > getMbufArray() const {
        return mbufArray;
    }

    void setMbufArray(std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> > mbufArray) {
        this->mbufArray = mbufArray;
    }

}
```

the get and set function have been auto generated for me.
I have generated out the swig java class using the information from other questions

```
%{
  define SWIG_JAVA_EXTRA_NATIVE_CONTAINERS 
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%{ 
 include <vector> 
%} 


%template(ProfileVector) std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> >;

%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> >::value_type { 
$result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(&$1), $descriptor(std::vector<mbuf>), 0 |  0 ); 
} 


%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> >::value_type & { 
    $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr($1), $descriptor(std::vector<mbuf>), 0 |  0 ); 
}
```

My problem is i still receive a SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_mbuf_t for my set and get types, i could create function that give me the elements but what i really need is more natural access to the vector elements in java.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want natural access to a vector or vectors from Java I suggest you write more of the wrapping code yourself either in C++ or Java or both.  Personally, I would write the whole thing in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out i was missing a typedef for the actual vector.

I now have acces to the mbuf type by adding the line to my .i file

```
%template(ProfileVector) std::vector<mbuf>;
%template(VectorProfileVector) std::vector<std::vector<mbuf> >;
```